# Discord.py: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id' error

Tags: attributeerror, discord.py

I had a kick command for discord, it was working 2 weeks ago but it doesn't work now. Here is the code and error

```
 @client.command()
async def kick(self, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await discord.Guild.kick(self=self, user=member, reason=reason)
```

**discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Context' object has no attribute 'id'**

I didn't understand why, I researched into the API, I think I did everything well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things incorrect,

First, all commands are passed a [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context) object as their first parameter, you can pass your Member object after. This object contains pretty much everything you'll need while processing commands.

Next, to get our guild we can retrieve it from the Context object, simply `ctx.guild`, and access the `.kick()` method from there.

Also, there's no need to pass the `self` object in, this is simply because we are within a class, I would recommend reading up on python object-oriented programming if you're not familiar with it, it'll help a lot with working with discord.py.

```
@client.command()
async def kick(self, ctx: commands.Context, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await ctx.guild.kick(user=member, reason=reason)
```

Comment: Actually it worked but in a diffirent way, I just changed discord.Guild.kick(self=self, user=member, reason=reason) to the ctx.guild.kick(user=member, reason=reason)